# Vim is putting two tabs whenever I punch in tab

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have the following settings to have two-space sized tab stops:

```
:set tabstop=2      
:set noexpandtab
:set shiftwidth=2
```

However, every time I hit Tab, two 2-space-width tabs go in. I just want a single 2-space-sized tab stop. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `shiftwidth`?

Comment: `:set shiftwidth=2`, it is also 2

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer, so that other users know that it worked and that the question has been answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `softtabstop` is set to 4? Try this:

```
:set tabstop=2
:set noexpandtab
:set shiftwidth=2
:set softtabstop=2
```